# Zero and Combine in Computation Expression

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I have the following computation expression builder:

```
type ExprBuilder() = 
    member this.Return(x) =
        Some x

let expr = new ExprBuilder()
```

I understand the purpose of methods *Return*, *Zero* and *Combine*, but I don't understand what is the difference between expressions shown below:

```
let a = expr{
    printfn "Hello"
    return 1
} // result is Some 1

let c = expr{
   return 1
   printfn "Hello"
} // do not compile. Combine method required
```

I also don't understand why in the first case *Zero* method in not required for *printfn* statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first expression, you perform some computation that results in value `1`, and that's it. You don't need a `Zero` in it, because `Zero` is only needed for `return`-less expressions (that's why it's called "zero" - it's what is there when nothing is there), and your expression does have a `return`.

To specifically answer your question, `Zero` is not required "*for the printfn statement*", because not every line within the expression gets transformed. When compiling computation expressions, the compiler breaks them up at "special" points, such as `let!`, `do!`, `return`, etc., leaving all the rest of the code between those points intact. In this case, your `printfn` call just becomes part of the code that executes before the `return`.

In the second expression, you perform *two* computations: the first one results in value `1`, and second one results in `Zero` (which is implicitly assumed when expression lacks a `return`). But the whole computation expression can't have two return values, it must have one. So in order to bring results of the two computations together (one might say, *combine* them), you need the `Combine` method.

Besides `Combine` and `Zero`, you'd also need to implement `Delay` for this to work. Multipart (i.e. "combined") computations are also wrapped in `Delay` in order to allow the builder to defer evaluation and possibly drop some parts within the `Combine` implementation.

I recommend reading through [this introduction](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-builder-part1/) by Scott Wlaschin, specifically [part 3 about `Delay` and `Run`](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-builder-part3/).